# How to upgrade ChromiumWebBrowser version in Windows Forms applications?

Tags: winforms, chromium, visual-studio-2019, cefsharp

I wanted to upgrade the version of ChromiumWebBrowser in my Windows Forms Application in Visual Studio Community version 2019. I found a file at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/commit/3ee5b4544a26cb227611d4d994e04be7228dbf44

How do I use this file to upgrade the version?

Comment: Look at https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/173/how-to-use-cefsharp-chromium-embedded-framework-csharp-in-a-winforms-application

Comment: Yes, but that article talks about how to install it for the first time. Anyway, after reading the article, I decided see through the steps and found out how to upgrade it within Visual Studio. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following the comments of [Oleg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuYCM.png), I just came across to know the correct way. In Visual Studio 2019, go to Project > Manage NuGet Packages. Select "Installed" tab and search for CefSharp. You will get CefSharp listed as you have already installed it. There, at the right hand side, when you mouseover, there is an "upgrade" arrow.

[image]

Click on it and you will be guided through the upgrade. You will get a success message after the upgrade.

Close Visual Studio 2019 and then restart it.